# Could not load package "\File System\ because of error 0x80070002. Description: Unable to find the specified file. Source: MsDtsSrvr

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

We are building a new environment having SQL server 2014 and migrating our SSIS job to the new environment.

We have a SSIS job named as **ABCD** (assume)

The job is deployed as file system deployment:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Packages\ABCD\ABCD.dtsx`

While executing, It gives an error as

> Could not load package "\File System\ABCD\ABCD because of error 0x80070002. Description: Unable to find the specified file. Source: MsDtsSrvr

Please suggest how to solve this issue, Also as the environment is controlled I am unable to try changes

Comment: UNC path maybe?

Comment: might be Your specified file. Source: MsDtsSrvr is not available in the given path

Comment: @Long I am not sure what does UNC mean

Comment: @Srini131 The dtsx files are present on the path specified in the job. Also I believe intetgration services in installed and running in the machine

Comment: @FaizRahman, you specified the path, but that path might be accessed only by local not the target server, for any packages that need to be referenced to the job on different server, that should be on the shared drive and get used by UNC ( Universal Naming Convention ) path. You could switch to login in the target server, to check whether you could visit that path which your package resides. For example, C:\ is just your local drive, it is not recognizable by your target server

Comment: @LONG 
they both are on a single machine, I mean that the package is kept on the C drive of a machine and the job is also configured on the sql server installed on the very same machine.

Comment: @LONG
The package was initially designed in SSIS 2005. We have upgraded the package to run time 2014 version. The package is running fine in Development environment(2014, also hosted on sql agent) so I believe it should not be an upgradation issue.